# Should I mark-up code examples with <code> or a read-only <textarea> for screen readers?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers

I have a page with multiple HTML code examples. Would screen-reader users benefit from seeing them like this:

```
<textarea readonly="true">CODE EXAMPLE HERE</textarea>
```

or should I just go for this:

```
<code>CODE EXAMPLE HERE</code>
```

I'm thinking that the `<textarea>` might enable easier to copy-paste than the `<code>`, but I'd like to hear about your experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<textarea>` elements are for user input. `readonly` is designed to be a temporary state for something which *is* used for user input but might be frozen for some reason.

Use `<code>` (possibly combined with `<pre>`).

Comment: You make a good argument. I think oftentimes developers try to creatively manipulate components to do something they were not designed to do, and especially with assistive technology we should just rely on the semantically correct elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<code>` is the right solution. If ever there is a fitting HTML tag for a purpose just use it. The browser and screen reader will convert that into helpful information for the user. ARIA as stated by the W3C should only be used if no HTML solution is available. ARIA will force a kind of behaviour. This is often used for `div` tags which on their own have no semantic and arming them with ARIA roles and attributes can make them behave as visually implied.